# Using LinqtoSQL How do I update rows in a table depending on the value of a column in that row

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

`I am using LinqtoSql to update rows in an SQL Server database I am using the following code to accomplish this

```
   public void MarkClaimed()
   {
       using var UpdateContext = new PanelClassesDataContext(dbConnect);
       var rowsToUpdate = UpdateContext.PowerGenerateds.Where(row => row.Claimed == 'N');
       foreach (var row in rowsToUpdate)
       {
           row.Claimed = 'Y';
       }
       UpdateContext.SubmitChanges();
   }
```

The definition of the table is

Date    date    Unchecked
MeterReading    decimal(10, 2)  Unchecked
Generated   decimal(10, 2)  Unchecked
Value   decimal(10, 2)  Unchecked
Claimed nchar(1)    Unchecked

rowsToUpdate prior to the foreach loop (CSV format)
PowerGenerated,PowerGenerated._Date,PowerGenerated._MeterReading,PowerGenerated._Generated,PowerGenerated._Value,PowerGenerated._Claimed,PowerGenerated.Date,PowerGenerated.MeterReading,PowerGenerated.Generated,PowerGenerated.Value,PowerGenerated.Claimed
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"03/09/2023 00:00:00",39080.43,17.53,4.54,N,"03/09/2023 00:00:00",39080.43,17.53,4.54,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"29/08/2023 00:00:00",38995.70,895.70,232.21,N,"29/08/2023 00:00:00",38995.70,895.70,232.21,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"30/08/2023 00:00:00",39009.87,14.17,3.67,N,"30/08/2023 00:00:00",39009.87,14.17,3.67,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"01/09/2023 00:00:00",39026.51,16.64,4.31,N,"01/09/2023 00:00:00",39026.51,16.64,4.31,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"03/09/2023 00:00:00",39062.90,36.39,9.43,N,"03/09/2023 00:00:00",39062.90,36.39,9.43,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"05/09/2023 00:00:00",39121.83,41.40,10.73,N,"05/09/2023 00:00:00",39121.83,41.40,10.73,N

rowsToUpdate after the foreach loop. (CSV Format)
PowerGenerated,PowerGenerated._Date,PowerGenerated._MeterReading,PowerGenerated._Generated,PowerGenerated._Value,PowerGenerated._Claimed,PowerGenerated.Date,PowerGenerated.MeterReading,PowerGenerated.Generated,PowerGenerated.Value,PowerGenerated.Claimed
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"03/09/2023 00:00:00",39080.43,17.53,4.54,N,"03/09/2023 00:00:00",39080.43,17.53,4.54,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"29/08/2023 00:00:00",38995.70,895.70,232.21,N,"29/08/2023 00:00:00",38995.70,895.70,232.21,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"30/08/2023 00:00:00",39009.87,14.17,3.67,N,"30/08/2023 00:00:00",39009.87,14.17,3.67,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"01/09/2023 00:00:00",39026.51,16.64,4.31,N,"01/09/2023 00:00:00",39026.51,16.64,4.31,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"03/09/2023 00:00:00",39062.90,36.39,9.43,N,"03/09/2023 00:00:00",39062.90,36.39,9.43,N
SolarPanels.Linq.PowerGenerated,"05/09/2023 00:00:00",39121.83,41.40,10.73,N,"05/09/2023 00:00:00",39121.83,41.40,10.73,N

The before and after CSVs show that the foreach loop does not update rowToUpate and hence the SubmitChanges does not update the rows in the database.

I an using Visual Studio 2022 17.7, .net7 and MindBox LinqtoSQL all are at the latest available  update status.
I am not a very experienced programmer and I cant work out why the foreach loop does not update rowsToUpdate can anyone suggest where I am going wrong``

I have tried to access rowsToUpdate directly but I have failed in this

Answer (score 0):

You should convert rowsToUpdate to List object. Like below:

```
var rowsToUpdate = UpdateContext.PowerGenerateds.Where(row => row.Claimed == 'N').ToList();
```

According your code, I write the test sample below for you.

```
public void MarkClaimed()
{
    try
    {
        using var UpdateContext = new PanelClassesDataContext(dbConnect);

        // Enable logging 
        UpdateContext.Log = Console.Out;

        // fetch the rows from the database then into memory.
        var rowsToUpdate = UpdateContext.PowerGenerateds.Where(row => row.Claimed == 'N').ToList();

        foreach (var row in rowsToUpdate)
        {
            row.Claimed = 'Y';
            // Add this line
            UpdateContext.PowerGenerateds.Attach(row, true);
        }

        UpdateContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Jason Thank you for the code, I tried and it failed at the Attach statement, the exception message was CannotPerformCUDOnReadOnlyTable: Table(PowerGenerated). However that set me thinking and I have solved the problem by writing a simple stored procedure in the database which I call from the UpdateContext.